# How to read/fetch file from jquery plugins

Tags: jquery

I am using this [plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Drag-Drop-File-Upload-Dialog-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html).

Can Any one help me how to get file from this.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#open_btn").click(function() {
    alert("fal");

     $.FileDialog({

          accept: "*",
          cancelButton: "Close",
          dragMessage: "Drop files here",
          dropheight: 150,
          errorMessage: "An error occured while loading file",
          multiple: true,
          okButton: "OK",
          readAs: "DataURL",
          removeMessage: "Remove&nbsp;file",
          title: "Load file(s)",      

      });
    });

    });
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What are you trying to achieve exactly? Where should the file be gotten from?

Comment: Thanks for Reply,
Sir, Exaclty i have to use drag and drop (Multiple) file uploading and uploaded file save to database , thats why i choose Jquery Plugins :

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Drag-Drop-File-Upload-Dialog-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html

Please Help Mi Out